# Piping data from a file to a rendered page in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream, sails.js

My application needs to read in a large dataset and pipe it to the client to manipulate with D3.js. The problem is, on large datasets, the reading/loading of the file contents could take a while. I want to solve this using streams. However, I'm unsure of how to do so in the context of the Sails framework.

What I want to do is read the contents of the file and pipe it to a rendered page. However, I can't figure out how to pipe it through if I use something like `res.view('somePage', { data: thePipedData });`.

I currently have something like this:

```
var datastream = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(DATASET_EXTRACT_PATH, datatype, dataset, dataset + '.csv'));
datastream.pipe(res); 
...
return res.view('analytics', { title: 'Analytics', data: ??? });
```

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your example it seems like the best course of action would be to set up a separate endpoint to serve just the data, and include it on the client via a regular `<script>` tag.

**MyDataController.js**

```js
getData: function(req, res) {

    /* Some code here to determine datatype and dataset based on params */

    // Wrap the data in a Javascript string
    res.write("var theData = '");
    // Open a read stream for the file
    var datastream = fs.createReadStream(
        path.resolve(DATASET_EXTRACT_PATH, datatype, dataset, dataset + '.csv')
    );
    // Pipe the file to the response.  Set {end: false} so that res isn't closed
    // when the file stream ends, allowing us to continue writing to it.
    datastream.pipe(res, {end: false});
    // When the file is done streaming, finish the Javascript string
    datastream.on('end', function() {
        res.end("';");
    });

}
```

**MyView.ejs**

```
<script language="javascript" src="/mydata/getdata?datatype=<%=datatype%>&etc.."></script>
```

**MyViewController.js**

```
res.view('analytics', {datatype: 'someDataType', etc...});
```

A slight variation on this strategy would be to use a JSONP-style approach; rather than wrapping the data in a variable in the data controller action, you would wrap it in a function.  You could then call the endpoint via AJAX to get the data.  Either way you'd have the benefit of a quick page load since the large data set is loaded separately, but with the JSONP variation you'd also be able to easily show a loading indicator while waiting for the data.

Comment: Thanks! If I use those script tags, how do I access the data within those tags?

Comment: In the simple case where `MyDataController.getData` outputs `var theData='<csv data>';`, it'll be exposed as a global var called `theData` that you can use in other scripts on the page (or even other external scripts, provided they are loaded after the `/getdata` script tag)

Comment: Great, this is perfect!